# Merging php foreach loops into one

Tags: magento-1.9, php, html, grouped-products

I am trying to display attributes of simple products on a grouped product page. I have everything setup to pull the info. My issue is how to display it correctly.
I have two foreach loops that display the data but I get:

**Manufacturer: UPC: Manufacturer Part Number:** X-Stream0100055PLV-A-B

When I want it to be

**Manufacturer:** X-Stream
**UPC:** 0100055
**Manufacturer Part Number:** PLV-A-B

The code used is

```
<?php foreach($gridattributes as $attrib){
echo '<b>'.$this->htmlEscape($attrib[label]).': </b>';} ?>

<?php foreach($gridattributes as $attribname=>$attribval){
echo ''.$this->htmlEscape($_item->getData($attribname)).'';} ?>
```

How can I merge these to display as my second example?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have You tried as below ?

```
<?php foreach($gridattributes as $attribname=>$attribval):?>
    <b><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($attribval['label']);?></b>
    <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getData($attribname));?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: That does it perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @jrl2222 you can accept and up vote then

Comment: When I upvote it says  
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: yes. it will show as up vote when you have 15+ reputation